# Unable to use ngModel / *ngFor inside a custom third party web component in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, web-component

I'm creating a select dropdown by using some abc third party tag. But in UI no options are getting displayed. It seems as if ngFor is not working at all.

```
  <p-is-abc-select mode="action" hide-on-scroll label="Airline Name">
        <select [(ngModel)]="airlineSelected">
          <option *ngFor="let airline of airLines" [value]="airline.name">
            {{airline.name}} </option>
          <option value="">"No airline"</option>
        </select>

   </p-is-abc-select>
```

The above piece of code works fine when using native select and option inn normal html without 3rd party tag name.

Comment: I suspect, since `*ngFor` is inside `<p-is-abc-select>`, then it's expecting `airLines` to be defined in that component, which it probably isn't. It's probably defined in the current component (the parent).

Comment: @JeremyThille That might be the case but thing is <p-is-abc-select> is a custom web component provided by 3rd party(abc company) for styling and js part. So it's not even possible to alter there js/ts files and add airLines property. I guess there must be some way to let angular know that it should  look for properties in its own rspc ts file and not into custom web component.

Comment: In this case, you can place your data in a service, and access it directly from the template : `*ngFor="let airline of myService.airLines"`

Comment: There are lots of properties (dropdowns, input boxes, date pickers, paginations) and moving all of them to service is not a good way. As these properties are intended to be used only in there own rspc components and not by any other components.

Answer (score 0):

Adding ngIf does the trick. As dropdown was getting rendered before `airLines` data was populated by async call. Doing `*ngIf` waits for the data first and then renders dropdown with options.

```
<p-is-abc-select ngIf="airLines.length>0" mode="action" hide-on-scroll label="Airline Name">
        <select [(ngModel)]="airlineSelected">
          <option *ngFor="let airline of airLines" [value]="airline.name">
            {{airline.name}} </option>
          <option value="">"No airline"</option>
        </select>

   </p-is-abc-select>
```